# Switching View Controllers over Swift code

Tags: swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, switching

I'm tryin' to switch View Controllers with Swift on a project I'm working on. I want it to switch between ViewController -> SecondViewController. So I'm putting this code into the ViewController.Swift and NOT into SecondViewController.

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondController") as! SecondViewController
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
```

I get a thread 1 : signal SIGABRT.

If I do have to put my code into the SecondViewController, where would I put it?

Comment: Where do you get `signal SIGABRT` ? What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondController") as! SecondViewController
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: true)
```

Are your all view controller's are in navigation controller container?

Comment: Did you put view controller's in UINavigationController. If you have put in navigation controller, the crash is somewhere else.